# Why when I set a direction to the textarea, its value changes?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, regex

Well actually my problem is very tiny .. You need glasses to see it `:-)`. Ok please do the following:

1. run the code snippet
2. write `..!` into the textarea
3. then write an space after it
4. then write `س` after it
5. now as you see, the space between dots in `..!` will be changed.

Why? Again, the problem is really negligible, but it is on my nerves. Why when I set a direction to the textarea *(like `rtl`)*, the value of that textarea will be changed *(a bit)* ?

Here is my code:

```js
$("body").on('input', 'textarea', function() {
  
      var el  = $(this);
      var len = el.val().length;
  
    // declare direction of comment in textarea
    var x = /^[^a-zآ-ی]*[a-z]/i; // is ascii
   var isAscii = x.test(el.val());
 if(isAscii){
  el.css("direction", "ltr");
 } else {
  el.css("direction", "rtl");
 }
  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea>dynamic direction</textarea>
```

Comment: I don't see anything. I really need glasses :-P

Comment: @Rohit Let me help you .. [The number of dots are identical in both cases, but the second one is wider. Why?](http://i.stack.imgur.com/lYufd.jpg)

Comment: I saw your image but can't replicate the issue at my end. Let me know which browser you are using?